# My follow-up to a relevant question was deleted. Why?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I have a question about my Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange post: [Stop Google Search Opening in Chrome](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/146149/stop-google-search-opening-in-chrome/185390#185390)

I believe my post was very relevant to the main post.   I was simply looking for a related answer.   I have looked everywhere on quite a few board and can't find a dang thing on this problem.   I feel that a link to my question is at least warranted to link the answers for anyone else searching.

If I am wording it wrong, let me know.

Answer (score 9):

[This site isn't a forum.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/350567) There aren't "follow-ups" here: there are **questions** and **answers**. If you want to ask a question, use the **Ask question** button. If you know the answer to a question, write it in **Your answer** under that question. It doesn't matter how relevant it is: if it's not an answer to the question, it doesn't belong there. People who know the answer to your question won't see it if it's not posted as a question, and they can't help you, because you can't answer an answer.

Running the site in this format is what makes it a repository of information that's easy to find and navigate, without the problems of thread hijacking and "me too" posts that you get on a forum. It means that people who know about the thing you're asking about will see your question on the front page of the site: you're not relying on them looking on the n-th page of a thread about a related question that they're not going to look at because they already know the answer.

The [tour](https://android.stackexchange.com/tour) is a really brief introduction to all of this. You get a badge for reading it, but more importantly, you also learn how to get your questions answered by experts.